# How to post a form data when datalist option is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery code to get selected option , but when i post my form's data to database nothing happens , but when i test with `console.log` shows me that select action was changed.

```js
$('#names').change(function() {
  $.post('/fuel/driver', $('fuelForm').serialize(), function(data) {
      // success
    }, 'json');
});
```

```html
<form role="form" id="fuelForm">
  <input type="text" class="form-control col-lg-4" placeholder="Select driver's name" name="names" id="names" list="saved_driver_name">
  <datalist id="saved_driver_name">
    <option value="">----</option>
    @for(i <- FuelHistory.fuel()) {
      <option value="@i.driver.names">@i.driver.names</option>
    }
  </datalist>
</form>
```

Comment: `$('fuelForm')` should be `$('#fuelForm')`. Voting to close as typo.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use  `$('#fuelForm')`. You're missing the id-selector

```
$('#names').change(function() {
  $.post('/fuel/driver', $('#fuelForm').serialize(), function(data) {
    // success
  }, 'json');
});
```

Comment: Please just vote to close obvious typos, leaving a comment if one hasn't already been made. Answering them helps no one and only prevents the question from being garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery form selector should be fixed like `$('#fuelForm')`

```
$('#names').change(function() {
  $.post('/fuel/driver', $('#fuelForm').serialize(), function(data) {
      // success
    }, 'json');
});
```

Comment: Please just vote to close obvious typos, leaving a comment if one hasn't already been made. Answering them helps no one and only prevents the question from being garbage collected.